# How to parse contents of raw email message into a pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, list, winapi, pywin32

I am attempting to use a python script to go through my outlook inbox and store the body of emails with a specific subject into a pandas dataframe.  So far, I have been able to access my inbox and search all of my emails for my desired subject and then stored the body of the email into a list.  To do so, I used the win32.client library with the following code
'''

```
import win32com.client
import time
import datetime as dt
from os import path
import pandas as pd
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 

messages = inbox.Items
contents = []
for m in messages:
    if 'XXXX XXXXX XXXX' in m.Subject :
        contents.append((m.body))


df = pd.DataFrame(contents)

arr = [a.split("\r\n") for a in contents]
```

'''
which yields the following result :

Largest Increase In Risk By Dollar Amount

CM Name                                            CM         AT   ID   Risk Increase/(Decrease)     Risk Increase %     % of Net Capital      ETH Elig

---

ABN AMRO Clearing Chicago LLC                      xxxx     M    N              78,776,523                      149.3                   12.6 Y
Credit Suisse Securities (USA) LLC                 xxxx      C                   26,806,976                        2.6                    0.3 Y
Goldman Sachs & Co. LLC                            xxxx      M    N              19,121,988                       15.7                    0.0 Y
SG Americas Securities, LLC                        xxxx      C                   12,574,954                       13.2                    0.2 Y
Robinhood Securities, LLC                         xxxx      C                   11,729,669                      179.7                    4.7 N
TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc.                       xxxx     C                   11,415,323                        5.7                    0.3 N
Jefferies LLC                                      xxxx      C                    9,923,448                       16.4                    0.7 N
Wells Fargo Securities, LLC                        xxxx      C                    8,990,763                        2.2                    0.1 Y
J.P. Morgan Securities LLC                         xxxx      F                    8,838,248                        0.6                    0.0 Y
SG Americas Securities, LLC                        xxxx      C                    8,203,265                       24.8                    0.1 Y

Largest Increase In Risk As % Of Net Capital

CM Name                                            CM         AT   ID   Risk Increase/(Decrease)     Risk Increase %     % of Net Capital      ETH Elig

---

ABN AMRO Clearing Chicago LLC                      xxxx      M    N              78,776,523                      149.3                   12.6 Y
Robinhood Securities, LLC                          xxxx     C                   11,729,669                      179.7                    4.7 N
Hilltop Securities Inc.                            xxxx     F                    6,779,534                       47.7                    2.7 N
Phillip Capital Inc.                               xxxx      C                      696,778                       10.8                    1.3 Y
StockCross Financial Services, Inc.                xxxx     F                      207,372                       40.4                    1.1 N
Lek Securities Corporation                         xxxx      C                      144,803                       10.8                    1.0 N
Jefferies LLC                                      xxxx      C                    9,923,448                       16.4                    0.7 N
Wedbush Securities Inc.                            xxxx      F                    1,009,205                       15.3                    0.5 N
E D & F Man Capital Markets Inc.                   xxxx      C                      923,893                        6.3                    0.4 Y
ABN AMRO Clearing Chicago LLC                      xxxx      M    N               2,974,657                       58.7                    0.4 Y

Largest Decrease In Risk By Dollar Amount

CM Name                                            CM         AT   ID   Risk Increase/(Decrease)     Risk Decrease %     % of Net Capital      ETH Elig

---

TD Ameritrade Clearing, Inc.                       xxxx      C                  -58,006,018                       -5.9                    1.7 N
UBS Securities LLC                                 xxxx      C                  -43,626,425                       -9.8                    1.0 Y
Merrill Lynch Professional Clearing Corp.          xxxx      M    N             -39,163,279                       -6.1                    0.5 Y
National Financial Services LLC                    xxxx      C                  -35,518,333                       -3.0                    0.7 Y
ABN AMRO Clearing Chicago LLC                      xxxx      M    N             -33,584,651                      -27.0                    5.3 Y
E*TRADE Securities LLC                             xxxx      C                  -28,706,087                       -6.8                    2.1 N
TD Prime Services LLC                              xxxx      F                  -28,362,239                       -6.9                    3.7 Y
Charles Schwab & Co., Inc.                         xxxx      C                  -24,738,164                       -3.2                    0.7 N
J.P. Morgan Securities LLC                         xxxx      C                  -16,521,434                       -2.4                    0.0 Y
Interactive Brokers LLC                            xxxx      C                  -15,815,411                       -4.0                    0.3 Y

The arr object is interpreted as a list of lists.  And each list within arr contains 64 elements.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to convert these raw email messages into an object that I can perform analyses on, but I can't figure out how to parse my list of lists such that the data can be read into a dataframe in the same order it is presented in the email.

Any help is much appreciated.